# Callout labels are wrong in GeoListPlot

Tags: geography, geographics

```
areas = {"Belize", "Guatemala", "Honduras", "Haiti", 
   "Saint Kitts and Nevis", "Saint Lucia", 
   "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Paraguay", "Marshall Islands",
    "Nauru", "Palau", "Tuvalu", "Eswatini", "Vatican"};

GeoListPlot[Callout[Entity["Country", #], #] & /@ areas]
```

[image: output plot]

I don't know why the label `Paraguay` or `Marshall Islands` appears in the wrong place. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your names are not the standard that Entity uses. However, you can use SemanticInterpration to turn "free form" text into entities, and it works for all of your data:

```
areaNames = {...all your names here...};
areaEntities = SemanticInterpretation /@ areaNames
```

Since you're using GeoListPlot, you can just set the GeoLabels option to true:

```
GeoListPlot[areaEntities, GeoLabels -> True]
```

On the other hand, if you want to use your original areaNames as labels, you might have to pair those names with the entities and apply Callout (somewhat similar to what you originally tried, but with pairs, i.e. two arguments):

```
GeoListPlot[Callout @@@ Transpose[{areaEntities, areaNames}]]
```

Comment: I note `Interpreter["Country"][areaNames]` always faster than `SemanticInterpretation`, and it has caching

Answer (score 3):

**With Callout**

1. Use names that the engine recognizes for the countries. Some assistance can be had from the free form linguistic input.
2. Divide this task into three pictures to get readable outputs as these countries span a large part of the globe.

---

```
c1 = Entity["Country", #] & /@ {"Belize", "Guatemala", "Honduras", 
   "Haiti", "SaintKittsNevis", "SaintLucia", "SaintVincentGrenadines",
    "Paraguay"}
c2 = Entity["Country", #] & /@ {"Nauru", "Palau", "Tuvalu", 
   "MarshallIslands"}
c3 = Entity["Country", #] & /@ {"Swaziland", "VaticanCity"}
```

The following seems to work for `{c1,c2,c3}`:

```
GeoListPlot[Callout @@ Transpose[{#, #["Name"]}] & /@ c1]
```

---

```
GeoListPlot[
 Callout @@ Transpose[{#, #["Name"]}] & /@ Catenate[{c1, c2, c3}], 
 ImageSize -> Full, GeoRange -> "World", 
 GeoCenter -> Entity["City", {"Cairo", "Cairo", "Egypt"}]]
```

---

**Another option**

Use `GeoLabels` instead of `Callout`.

```
GraphicsRow[
 GeoListPlot[#, GeoLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Large] & /@ {c1, 
   c2, c3}]
```

I will not upload the picture as it is 139kB.